# Accessing key of an array on HTML check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tree with checkboxes and their id has key for item and value as their value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list_code[4]" id="list_code[4]" value="AG12345678" checked="checked">
```

When users select a tree element I can access those by

```
$('input[name^="list_code"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) 
        list_code = $(this).val();
});
```

I am able to get value `AG12345678` but I need to get key value too which is `4` from list_code[4] in this case. How can I access that value?

Comment: The answers so far seem like overkill. Just out of curiosity, how are you rendering your checkboxes?

Comment: `[` and `]` aren't valid characters for the `id` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @iambriansreed: Unless you're in an environment that only needs to target HTML5 browsers. Then they're fine.

Comment: @Robin I am using dynatree inside a dropdown box. When expanded users can select from tree or write to box which auto completes and selects auto completed element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var n = this.id.slice(this.id.indexOf('[') + 1, this.id.indexOf(']'));
```

or...

```
var n = this.id.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

or...

```
var n = (this.id.match(/\d+/) || [])[0];
```

or if there could be other unwanted numbers...

```
var n = (this.id.match(/\[(\d+)\]/) || [])[1];
```

---

Or if you control the source, a good solution would be to use a `data-` attribute for future HTML5 support...

```
<input type="checkbox" data-number="4" name="list_code[4]" id="list_code[4]" value="AG12345678" checked="checked">
```

...then in HTML5 browsers, you could do...

```
this.data.number;
```

...or for legacy support, you could do...

```
this.getAttribute('data-number');
```

Comment: +1 although I don't usually vote on answers that I am competing with

Comment: @ajax333221: Is it a competition? ;) I upvoted the other answers to even things out.

Comment: I used this.id.replace(/\D/g, '') and works fine. Just curious is .split has more overhead than .replace ?

Comment: @PoX: Generally I'd assume it does since it needs to create an Array, but the difference will be minor overall.

Comment: @PoX but that will replace every non-numeric chars, so `list2_code[4]` will be `24`, just be careful (or use `.split(/\[|\]/)[1]`)

Answer (score 2):

With this:

```
this.getAttribute("id").split(/\[|\]/)[1];
```

Explanation:

- `this.getAttribute("id")` gets the id `"list_code[4]"`
- `split(/\[|\]/)` splits it into `["list_code","4",""]`
- `[1]` takes the element at index `1` which is `4`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('input[name^="list_code"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        list_code = $(this).val();
        key = parseInt($(this).attr('name').replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
});
```

If you find your field name attributes have numbers outside the index then do the following:

```
        key = parseInt($(this).attr('name').split('[')[1].replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));
```